# How to eliminate decimal places from a built-in sql function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server query:

```
select max(AveragePrice) as [LARGEST AVERAGE]
from
    (select b.brand_id, round(avg(prod_price),2) as AveragePrice
    from lgbrand b, lgproduct p
    where b.brand_id = p.brand_id
    group by b.brand_id) x
```

Output

```
LARGEST AVERAGE
22.590000
```

How do I trim the decimals to only show "22.59"?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using - answers may vary materially between them.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is best to leave display issues to the presentation layer. But at least you have learned a lesson though you might not understand it fully. It is the datatype that is important. Rounding a number does not generally change the datatype.

Comment: Trim the value in the client code or reporting tool rather than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROUND` to round up or down to specified number of decimal places.

```
select round(max(AveragePrice),2) as [LARGEST AVERAGE]
from
    (select b.brand_id, round(avg(prod_price),2) as AveragePrice
    from lgbrand b, lgproduct p
    where b.brand_id = p.brand_id
    group by b.brand_id) x
```

Comment: I've tried this and it still returns the same output 22.590000

Comment: have you tried `CAST(max(AveragePrice) as DOUBLE)`?

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a hint to try cast as decimal and now it is working.  This is what I I used:

select cast(max(AveragePrice)as decimal(5,2)) as [LARGEST AVERAGE]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `FORMAT` for that:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX(averageprice),'#0.00') AS largest_average,...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below methods to convert to 2 decimal places.

```sql
declare @table table(val decimal(8,6))
insert into @table 
values (22.590000)

select Format(val,'##.##') from @table
SELECT cast(val as decimal(4,2)) from @table
SELECT convert(decimal(4,2), val) from @table
```

> 22.59